# Generating Multiple Thumbnails Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation, thumbnails, nsurl

I am attempting to load multiple thumbnails from a video url into a UIImageView. I can't seem to figure it out; I currently found how to just load a single thumbnail, but can't seem to figure out how to do it for multiple.

Here is the code:

```
private func thumbnailForVideoAtURL(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {

    let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    var time = asset.duration
    time.value = min(time.value, 2)

    do {
        let imageRef = try assetImageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    } catch {
        print("error")
        return nil
    }
}
```

&& within my viewDidLoad:

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: self.view.frame.height / 2, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)
        imageView.image = thumbnailForVideoAtURL(url: url!)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: You can use UITableView or CollectionView to load multiple thumbnails.

Comment: i think that would be excessive dont you think? my overall objective is to implement this into a uirange, which i have done, but i just need multiple pins now

Answer (score 1):

You should use `generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes:completionHandler:)` method instead of `copyCGImage(at:actualTime:)`

> AVAssetImageGenerator uses the default enabled video track(s) to generate images. Generating a single image in isolation can require the decoding of a large number of video frames with complex interdependencies. If you require a series of images, you can achieve far greater efficiency using the asynchronous method, generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes:completionHandler:), which employs decoding efficiencies similar to those used during playback.